# Google Play downloads never update

Tags: google-play

So I published an app about 3 weeks ago and it still says 10 downloads, but I have google analytics in the app and it says my app has nearly 1000 downloads. After 2 days my app said 10 downloads and it has never updated since then.

Has this ever happened to any of you? I have heard of a few days to a week of delay but 3 weeks is ridiculous. It should have updated by now.